# MathJax on Chat

Tags: discussion, mathjax, chat

Is there MathJax support on the chat?

Comment: How about you split this into a separate question and accepted answer?

Comment: I'll accept in two days (can't accept sooner).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this point there is no MathJax support in the chat system, but [this meta.MSE thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297/622) includes some information on how to overcome this issue.