# Editing titles to include $\mathfrak{LaTeX \; Math}$

Tags: discussion, titles

Should question titles, which sometimes intentionally avoid LaTeX math for those who choose faster rendering, be edited to insist upon LaTeX math? A recent instance that prompted my question is "[two tetrahedra in R^4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47672/two-tetrahedra-in-mathbb-r4)." The original title used R^4 to mean $\mathbb{R}^4$, and it was edited, bringing a 1.5-yr-old post to the front page. I don't object to the editing—I just want to know what the community considers appropriate.

Comment: As some meta.MO users will know, I am strongly against such edits in titles, and against them by and large in the body of text. Each insertion of mathbb makes me want to change it to mathbf, more often than not

Comment: As part of question initiated by @YemonChoi on this general matter I specifically carried out a "poll" on almost exactly this http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/169/whats-our-consensus-on-people-resurrecting-old-questions-just-to-edit-formattin/299#299 at this moment 8 against 7 for such an edit (excluding my personal opinion, which would be against, but also see my conclusion). [Some of the comments there started to be on tagging, you can ignore them.]

Comment: I rejected the edit, as too minor, but so it goes. Ridiculous that the body of the question, where R^4 was also used in many places, was not touched. If one is to make an edit on this question, the reasonable thing is to edit it fully, adding latex everywhere it is missing, and being consistent with the use of notation. (I do not have time for that right now, as it turns out, so I am not going to "improve it".)

Comment: I reverted the edit before seeing this thread. I hate unnecessary latex in titles because it makes the site slow on weak wifi or cellular connections on mobile devices. And it makes no sense to do it for long forgotten posts.

Answer (score 27):

Unlike Benjamin Steinberg, I have no objections to ${\rm\LaTeX}$ in titles of questions. I often use the site (even from mobile devices) where there is a sufficient speed for loading everything fairly fast.

I do, however, object to making this sort of edit to an old post. If you are going to improve the post, it should be an overall improvement, perhaps to another answer or so. But since a thread is bump, I expect a correlation between how old the thread is and how significant the improvement is, and in this case I don't think it's enough to merit such an edit.

Comment: -1 for 1st para and +1 for 2nd para :-)

Comment: +1 for first paragraph, and -1 for second. :-)

Comment: @Joel: My point in the second paragraph is the same as Andres' in the comments. If you are going to make an edit to an extremely old post, at least make it a good one. Not just one detail in the title.

Comment: I appreciate any kind of improvement, even small ones. I like to see old questions resurrected occasionally---I enjoy reading them---and I don't mind if a lot of questions get bumped. I think we could be more tolerant for what are at bottom good improvements.

Comment: The point with the thread in question was that this was not really a good improvement, however well intentioned. Instead, it added noise (in the form of a clash of notation).

Comment: Joel, I think you meant (-:

Comment: I just made an edit to bump. Also to fix something, if one wants to take that point of view :)

Comment: @Yemon: I'm amused that you put braces there. :-P

Comment: I had recently been on an informal hunt for LaTeXing-title-only edits to tell the editors about precisely this MMO question, but then I noticed your own recent [LaTeXing-title-only edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/413735/3).  Is the consensus that it is OK to make such small changes to posts, as long as they are already on the front page?

Answer (score 17):

No, they should not. Many of us habitually read MO on mobile devices with unreliable wifi/cellular connections and if most titles take a long time to render it makes the whole experience irritating. Latex should only be used in titles when really necessary. In fact I think one should in general be a latex minimalist in questions and answers too.

Comment: I take your point, Ben.  But equally, many of us habitually read MO on reliable high-speed broadband, and so prefer to see properly typeset mathematics rather than pseudo-tex code.  I don't think users should feel inhibited from using Latex in their questions and answers, but I think it would be a sensible compromise to be very sparing with it in titles, for the reason you give.  After all, how many of us register the difference between R^4 and $\mathbb{R}^4$ anyway?

Comment: Since $R^4$ is used in the body of the question, I believe here the intention was to replace R^4 with $R^4$. This being too small an edit, additional characters had to be added and R^4 became $\mathbb R^4$. The point is that it was *too small an edit*. I really don't see what the point of editing this was to begin with.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, could they have not changed the title to <b>R<b><sup>4</sup>, or does html not work in titles?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Don't know. That may be a useful alternative.

Comment: @TomLeinster, if people want to make their title in latex, I won't go and deliberately deTeXify it, but my gripe is when people TeXify a readable title that may have been purposely $deTeXified$ to be readable quickly.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I doubt HTML will work in titles. Titles already do not support most of the MarkDown markups; I would find it incredible if the software does not also strip HTML tags.

Comment: @WillieWong, you are right.  I just tried it.

Comment: @TomLeinster I'm afraid your comment reads a bit as "It works for *me* so what's the problem?".  Even on a decent speed broadband, I get a flicker as MathJaX renders it from TeX to MathML which is very annoying, and the page adjusts as the rendering occurs which makes it difficult to quickly scan through the question titles, so my vote is for **no** TeX in titles at all.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: but then the same user edited a day or so before '<=' to '\le' (okay twice, but that was all) with you approving it. My point is not to complain about this or what you say now, only I would like to point out (generally) that what is and is not 'too minor' is apparently decided by quite a small margin.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: well, Ben was arguing that the community should adopt a certain behaviour because of his own personal way of using MO, and I was doing just the same.  I think we're both being completely reasonable.  Surely lots of people do read MO on flaky connections, and surely lots of people read it on good university connections.  In the absence of data, we can only relate our personal experiences, express personal preferences, and make educated guesses as to what others want.

Comment: @TomLeinster The problem with that is that the two extremes are not balanced.  If there is no MathJaX in titles then people on fast connections are hardly inconvenienced at all, but if there is a lot of MathJaX in titles then people on slow connections are greatly inconvenienced to the point that the site becomes unusable.  I remember when jsMath was first put on and I was on a very slow connection in Rio and MO became unusable because I couldn't get past the question page.  So I don't think you're being equally completely reasonable!

Comment: @AndrewStacey I essential agree with you (and on my notebook the question-page regularly "freezes" everything, for quite a while), but also note that Tom Leinster suggested to be very sparing with TeX in titles, so I feel his position is rather balanced.

Comment: @quid I think it is the "but equally" that set the tone of the comment for me and to which I'm reacting (possibly over-reacting!).  The two positions are not equal and a "compromise" is not one.

Comment: I agree with quid that my position is rather balanced :-).  I'm suggesting using Latex very sparingly in titles, after all.

Comment: Anyway, Andrew, I bet your connection's faster than mine (which is nothing special).  I think this is also to do with personal preference: would you accept a bit of delay and flicker if the reward was properly typeset maths?  I suspect you wouldn't, and I would.

Comment: Now that we have SE 2.0, is it possible to implement a feature that de$\LaTeX$ifies titles?

Comment: I am not well-informed on technicalities here, but I think--mainly from observation how my devices behave--that the quality of the internet-connection is not the only or even the main issue. Rather the page when there is a lot of MathJax seems pretty demanding on the hardware.

Comment: @TomLaGatta I am not sure how to interpret the 'now' or what you mean precisely, since before the move MathJax rendering in titles (at least in lists) was *optional* with default *off*. But I agree(?) it would be nice to get this back. I actually asked for this before the move, if it were possible; likely fell a bit through the cracks, maybe worth reasking.)

Comment: @quid It is certainly possible to inject Mathjax in and out any page with browser tricks and extensions only, independently of the settings in the page itself. It's not as easy as ticking a box (as in the old site), but it works. My suggestion would be defaulting to off in the main page, and referring the users wanting LaTeX in titles to this solution: http://checkmyworking.com/misc/mathjax-bookmarklet/

Comment: @Asaf is that link correct?

Comment: @Federico: Or [the ChatJax bookmark](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/44/mathjax-on-chat) made by the math.SE moderator, robjohn (although he made it long before he was elected to be a moderator).

Comment: I think the con arguments I have read so far (e.g. speed, preferring mathbf to mathbb, etc.) also apply to the body of questions and answers and therefore are not strong con arguments. If you prefer not to render MathJax (e.g. for speed) you can turn it off I think.

Comment: @Kavesh, I disagree. The slow rendering on answers and questions are not as irritating, although I did suggest being minimalist in this regards to.  If you are trying to quickly scan the questions on a small mobile the slow rendering makes things jumpy and sometimes the whole screen jumps to accommodate the rendering of one title while I am reading another.  If I actually care enough to open the question then I just wait for the whole thing to render and so don't have the annoyance of reading something with the screen jumping.

Comment: I would recommend against using HTML to format mathematics (like `<b>R<b><sup>4</sup>`), as this loses the semantics of the mathematics.  That makes it harder to programmatically recognize the mathematics within the page.  That makes it harder for things like screen readers (e.g., ChromeVox) to properly speak the mathematics, and makes it harder to copy and paste the math into CAS like Mathematica, and harder for search engines to properly identify the mathematics, etc.  Although I understand the need for practicality, it is also important to consider possible reuse of the page in the future.

Comment: Also, we are looking at speed improvements for MathJax (and mobile devices and networks also increase in speed), and in the future these short-term solutions may become liabilities (consider the [double-backslash](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/598/list-of-recurrent-technical-problems-involving-mathjax) issue currently being dealt with).  I think it is better to write what you mean than to fake it to get around current technical limitations.

Comment: @DavideCervone whatever happened to trying to write simple HTML to communicate ideas, rather than pretending HTML is some kind of Desktop publishing format? I think it is better to write simple approximations of what you mean and let **human readers** do the final parsing if need be

Comment: @YemonChoi, nothing has happened to that, but I'm you to not forget that your pages are used in other ways as well.  E.g., some of your human readers may need assistive technology (like screen readers) to "view" your answer, and in that case, marking the mathematics *as mathematics* (as opposed to just some additional text) can make a difference in their ability to understand what you have written.  A visual approximation is not always good enough. ...

Comment: Similarly, people who are searching for a particular answer are more likely to look for math in TeX notation than in HTML form since you can't really look for HTML tags.  So I'm not sure how you would search for `<b>R</b><sup>4</sup>` other than as `R4`, which I don't think I'd think to try.  But I *would* try `R^4`.  Again, with properly indicated mathematics, search engines (that know something about math) could find `\mathbb{R}^4` from a search for `R^4`, whereas there would be no way for them to recognize `<b>R</b><sup>4</sup>` as math, and so would not match that to `R^4`.

Comment: @DavideCervone in a "previous life" I looked at some aspects of web accessibility including screen readers, so point taken. My preference would be for R^4 without MathJax, by the way.

Answer (score 10):

Aside from rendering speed, there are other reasons why MathJax is undesirable in titles.

- Titles are also displayed in places where MathJax does not render, for example, in the browser's title for the page, and in the lists of questions in the [StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231730/please-add-tex-rendering-in-titles-on-the-ios-app) [apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221927/mathjax-borks-in-titles-in-android-app).
- The URL is created from the title and then will contain it with some symbols removed.
- MathJax titles make searching more difficult, and might affect search engines negatively due to the relevance of the title and URL.

More generally, a title heavy on formulas is more often than not badly chosen, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure it's true about the search engines. I have in the title of my current window the plain MathJax code. Certainly Google's crawler sees the same.

Comment: I said that some characters are removed for the *URL*, for the title of the page I said is is does not render, which you confirm. And, I still believe that in general a couple of words are better for searching than some symbols and/or their corresponding source (not last since often there are somewhat different ways to get more or less the same visually).

Answer (score 4):

This is only marginal to the discussed issue (but I still think it is worth mentioning).

There were some discussion on this meta about possibility of not showing questions from MO in the network wide hot questions list: [Measures to separate math overflow from the rest of the stack exchange network](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1305/measures-to-separate-math-overflow-from-the-rest-of-the-stack-exchange-network) (Related: [Featured MO questions on the hot list: what benefits, if any, do these bring?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1350/featured-mo-questions-on-the-hot-list-what-benefits-if-any-do-these-bring)) This suggestion received some support, but it is not very likely that this is going to happen anytime soon.

Adding MathJax to the title prevents that particular question from being shown in the hot network question list: [Are the questions with TeX markup in titles excluded from Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237475/are-the-questions-with-tex-markup-in-titles-excluded-from-hot-network-questions) So some users can consider this as an advantage of having LaTeX/MathJax in the title. (Depending on their position about the issue of MathOverflow and hot network questions.)