# Formulas in the title of the questions

Tags: discussion, formatting

Why don't many of the people who ask a question in MO use math environment  for their formulas in the title of the questions?

Comment: Various users of the site are of the opinion that it is **not desirable** to use MathJax in titles; see this almost duplicate http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/591/editing-titles-to-include-mathfraklatex-math

Comment: For one, try clicking a question title that consists entirely of math environment.

Answer (score 5):

Granted this is a temporary reason,  but I and I suspect many other members use
smart phones with old browsers, where such rendering takes time.  This is tolerable
for questions, less so for the front page.  Also, question titles without symbols are
more friendly to web search indexing, so lots of people outside MO can find and have a better 
chance of understanding the question with a good romanized title.

Comment: On my new iphone with lte the rendering doesn't bother me as much as it used to. But it does slow things down on my old iPad 1 on wifi.

Answer (score 4):

Before the migration to Math.SE last year, the front page of MathOverflow did not render math mode formulas.  This may be a leftover habit.

Here's an old discussion: http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1040/latex-in-titles/

Comment: For thos that do not click through, let me add that the frontpage did not render math mode since it was decided it should be like this (it could have been rendered on MO 1.0, too). And, that it is rendered now can be seen as a regression of the upgrade to MO 2.0 (as opposed to an improvement).